# gradle java9 Could not target platform: 'Java SE 9' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'

Tags: java, gradle, java-9, eclipse-oxygen

I want to use java9 on my gradle project inside eclipse oxygen. When I
 run:

```
Run as> Gradle Test on  GreeterTest.java
```

with the following code:

```
package hello.test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;    
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;    
import hello.Greeter;

class GreeterTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
        assertEquals("Hello world", greeter.sayHello());
    }
}
```

and with the class I test as:

```
package hello;

public class Greeter {
  public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello world!";
  }
}
```

I get the error message

> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 9' using
>   tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.

My eclipse.init is

> ```
> -startup ../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
> --launcher.library /Users/stein/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_\1.1.550.v20170928-1359
> -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
> -showsplash org.eclipse.epp.package.common
> --launcher.defaultAction openFile
> --launcher.a/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin
> -vmargs
> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.9
> -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
> -XX:+UseG1GC
> -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
> --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
> -XstartOnFirstThread
> -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.9
> -Xms256m
> -Xmx1024m
> --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
> -Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
> -XstartOnFirstThread
> -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
> -Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
> -Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
> -Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
> ```

[I have added JAVA_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odTl9.png)

[I have added the build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y46c8.png)

[I have change the compile parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18crZ.png)

> I have set the compile parameter in the Build.Gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext.junit4Version        = '4.12'
ext.junitVintageVersion  = '4.12.2'
ext.junitPlatformVersion = '1.0.2'
ext.junitJupiterVersion  = '5.0.2'
ext.log4jVersion         = '2.9.0'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

jar {
    baseName = 'junit5-gradle-consumer'
    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

compileJava {
   sourceCompatibility = 9
   targetCompatibility = 9
}

compileTestJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 9
    targetCompatibility = 9
    options.compilerArgs += '-parameters'
}

junitPlatform {
    // platformVersion '1.0.2'
    filters {
        engines {
            // include 'junit-jupiter', 'junit-vintage'
            // exclude 'custom-engine'
        }
        tags {
            // include 'fast'
            exclude 'slow'
        }
        // includeClassNamePattern '.*Test'
    }
    // configurationParameter 'junit.jupiter.conditions.deactivate', '*'
    // enableStandardTestTask true
    // reportsDir file('build/test-results/junit-platform') // this is the default
    logManager 'org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager'
}

dependencies {
    // JUnit Jupiter API and TestEngine implementation
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitJupiterVersion}")

    // If you also want to support JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 tests
    testCompile("junit:junit:${junit4Version}")
    testRuntime("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:${junitVintageVersion}")

    // To avoid compiler warnings about @API annotations in JUnit code
    //testCompileOnly('org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0')

    // To use Log4J's LogManager
    testRuntime("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:${log4jVersion}")
    testRuntime("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:${log4jVersion}")

    // Only needed to run tests in an (IntelliJ) IDE(A) that bundles an older version
    testRuntime("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-   launcher:${junitPlatformVersion}")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    description = 'Generates gradlew[.bat] scripts'
    gradleVersion = '4.1'
}
```

> What must I do to get this to run?

Comment: how about cli with `./gradlew clean build`, does it work for you?

Comment: With the latest Intellij, it seems working fine for me.

Comment: You dont have Java9 SDK installed on machine nor are it set as JAVA_HOME + JAVA_PATH

Answer (score 19):

You should probably try to update your `JAVA_HOME` in system variables and 
Java version used in eclipse to be consistent to

```
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk9
```

In MacOSX, something like :

```
JAVA_HOME = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

As [informed in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500674/gradle-java9-could-not-target-platform-java-se-9-using-tool-chain-jdk-8-1/47502889?noredirect=1#comment94168224_47502889), the default path on Linux would be :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk
```

Answer (score 4):

From what I can see, it is the Gradle version issue. ([Gradle and Java 9 compatibility issue](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-determine-java-version-from-9-0-1/24457/8)).

You need to upgrade the wrapper to 4.3.1, cli ref:

```
# upgrade Gradle to 4.3.1 
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.3.1 # not ./gradlew
```

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 4):

I changed the `java_home` and upgraded Gradle. Now it is working.

Comment: The buidship pluging in eclips oxygen is not upgraded to JAVA 9 so i must use Java8

Comment: Try setting the JDK location on the Java Home tab of the Run Configuration and upgrade the wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the issue because in IntelliJ Idea in the Settings > Build Tools > Gradle
In "Gradle" section, Gradlje JVM used an incorrect Java version. So I specify to use JAVA_HOME and it fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the other ways you tried:

Gradle has a default JVM set in your `%userprofile%/.gradle/gradle.properties`.
This is in the folder "C:\Users\j.gradle\gradle.properties" for me:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-11.0.7.10-hotspot
```

That's where you should also put your newer JVM to make sure gradle can compile newer projects.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to fix this problem was I did this on my imported project build.gradle on  compileJava section I changed sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility into 8. It works for me. this happen when you import project from other resource, which is build in different version.

Answer (score 1):

in Eclipse make sure you have proper settings on Gradle build configuration.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error with different JDK version, so i used the following code which works fine.

```
compileJava {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.javaHome = file('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.5.jdk/Contents/Home')
    targetCompatibility = 11
    sourceCompatibility = 11
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with eclipse, I had to set JAVA_HOME in Properties -> Gradle.

Answer (score -2):

For me the problem was that I used

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10
}
```

but the project was configured for Java 1.8. So I changed these to 1_8 and it works.