# How to use OpenJDK 11 when deploying to Heroku?

Tags: java, gradle, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Java application to Heroku targeting OpenJDK 11. I've added a `system.properties` file to the root of my application with the following content, as per [Heroku instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version):

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

However, when I deploy, I get the following Gradle error:

```
Gradle app detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Building Gradle app...
-----> executing ./gradlew jar
       Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-all.zip

Welcome to Gradle 4.10!

[Gradle highlights]

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.
```

How can I get Heroku to detect and use the correct Java version?

Comment: It looks like you might be using an old version of Gradle, but I don't think you can upgrade it yourself on Heroku. [Which stack are you using](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#viewing-which-stack-your-app-is-using)?

Comment: It's a standalone jar that I want to run as a HTTP server. I'm using Gradle 4.10.2.

Comment: Gradle didn't support JDK 11 until version 5.0, released on November 26. I think you'll have to upgrade. If that works I can add a proper answer below.

Comment: Interesting, since it works locally with 4.10.2. I'll see if changing that makes any difference.

Comment: Make sure you upgrade the wrapper by running `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 5.0` and `git add . && git commit`. This will make sure Heroku uses the Gradle version you use locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle didn't officially support JDK 11 until [version 5.0](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/release-notes.html) (released November 26, 2018). Upgrading to that version or later should fix the issue.

See also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47500674/354577) about Java 9 support.

Comment: This may be true, but Heroku should still have installed JDK 11 (instead of `Installing JDK 1.8`). Make sure you have the `system.properties` file checked into Git once Gradle is ready for JDK 11.

Comment: "Make sure you have the `system.properties` file checked into Git once Gradle is ready for JDK 11"—yes, definitely. Otherwise Heroku will never see it.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I created a system.properties file with java.runtime.version=13 and snip-snap, easy peasy. Thank you!