# Could not target platform: 'Java SE 12' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I run the following command under the root path of my java spring boot (grade) project on my Terminal:

./gradlew clean check

But I get error message:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 12' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.
```

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: Update your jdk or reduce your target platform

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I looked for the same just now.

Gradle has a default JVM set in your `%userprofile%/.gradle/gradle.properties`.
This is in the folder "C:\Users\j.gradle\gradle.properties" for me:

That's where you should also put your newer JVM to make sure gradle can compile newer projects.
Looks like this now:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-11.0.7.10-hotspot
```

See also this thread where I posted the same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62564011/2807735

Comment: The equivalent file for Linux is "~/.gradle/gradle.properties"

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compile classes to Java 12, but you are using a Java 8 JDK.

If you type in *java -version* in console, you should see Java 8.
You need to install Java 12 or higher and put it on your PATH OR change your target to Java 8

Comment: I already installed Java 12. How to switch to 12 via Terminal command?

Answer (score 0):

As a result of another SO fix I had these sections in different parts `build.gradle (app)`:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1_8
    targetCompatibility 1_8
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1_7
    targetCompatibility 1_7
}
```

I removed second and the problem was fixed.