# How can I change JDK 1.8 to JDK 11 in Heroku?

Tags: java, heroku, web-deployment

I created pipelines for bitbucket to deploy app to Heroku. I use java 11 but Heroku installs 1.8.
[image]

How to fix it?

I also created `system.properties` in `main/resources` indicating JDK and Maven versions:

[image]

Comment: I think this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version) can help you

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to mention that I did it. [image](https://snipboard.io/gYabGD.jpg)

Comment: @DenisRomanenko, possibly you should add `system.properties` to the root directory of your application and check `JAVA_HOME` env variable as described here: [Could not target platform: 'Java SE 9' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500674/gradle-java9-could-not-target-platform-java-se-9-using-tool-chain-jdk-8-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a system.properties file in your directory and commit to git.
more info `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/customizing-the-jdk#prerequisites` see doc for more info.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to mention that I did it. [image](https://snipboard.io/gYabGD.jpg)

Comment: try with specify java version as `java.runtime.version=11` it will automatically select java 11.0.8. see here `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions`

Comment: This is my first question, this is why I forgot to note a lot of things. I also tried it.

Comment: You have to create `system.properties` file in your root directory not in `main/resources`, and don't forget to commit

Comment: Thanks @AbrarAnsari It helped me also, Regards! Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check what the `system.properties` file definitely got into your Git-repository by using `git ls-files`.

Secondly, check what the first 3 bytes of the file are not **UTF-8 BOM**.

Answer (score 0):

#### README

If you don't want to add a additional file (system.properties) in your code like me, then this answer would help.

---

Idea: Change java buildpack jdk default version from 1.8 to 11

Step:

1. Fork official java buildpack: `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java`. e.g. `https://github.com/archongum/heroku-buildpack-java`
2. Find out where the default jdk version variable is.

[image]

3. Commit changes and Push to GitHub
4. Add your own buildpack in Heroku
   [image]
5. Trigger deploy and done
   [image]